# Proportionally speaking, how many European refugees were accepted by Middle Eastern and African countries during World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two

[It is often claimed](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/06/02/the-forgotten-story-of-european-refugee-camps-in-the-middle-east/?utm_term=.341ab1bfd821) that Europe must accept refugees because the Middle East and Africa has accepted European refugees during World War 2.

But are there any precise statistics to show how many refugees were accepted by sovereign countries in those regions? Obviously it has to exclude territories that were European colonies at the time since those didn't really have a say in external matters.

Comment: @JonathanReez: no idea why you added this particular citation. It's interesting but it doesn't in the slightest support the "Europe must accept refugees because" claim you're making.

Comment: @Denis the claims are implicit rather than explicit.

Comment: In any case my question is valid even without the claims part.

Comment: Important differences are: a) many ME and African countries were not independent to chose how many refugees to accept b) the technologies of the day and the scale of the war made massive movement of civilians very difficult c) those who would have had more "incentives" to move away (Jews, Roma, etc.) were not allowed to do so... It is an "apples to oranges" comparation.

Comment: @SJuan76 I agree, which is why I think the shaming of Europeans through WWII history is completely idiotic

Comment: It's not often claimed. It is claimed - incorrectly - by very few people.

Comment: Are you asking about only independent countries? Only Turkey, Persia and Saudi Arabia were independent. Even Persia was occupied by the USSR and Britain for part of that time. All other middle Eastern countries were under the thumb of France, Britain or Italy to a greater or lesser extent during that time.

Comment: @NeMo yes, only independent countries

Comment: I think this question could be improved by making it about history rather than about current politics. Also the focus on independent countries seems artificial, as there were only four or five at that time (tr, sa, af, za and arguably ir, any others?)

Comment: Shouldn't Liberia also count as independent?

Comment: @gktscrk: yes, probably.

Answer (score 4):

This is anecdotal, and I have no idea how widespread  it was, but there were several German and Austrian Jewish academics  who fled  to Turkey in the 1930's  (Or at any rate, found themselves in Turkey then.)  Among them Richard von Mieses, Hilde Geiringer (mathematicians), Hans Güterbock (Hittitologist), Elizabeth Ettinghausen (Islamic & Byzantine art).

Turkey, at the time, was eager to import Western culture and many of the particular refugees I name took jobs in Turkish universities, where they must have enjoyed an approximation to civilized life, a life so absent then in their native countries.

Although this topic is of only peripheral interest to me I did spend a few minutes poking around.  Wikipedia, of course, has its [say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Turkey), with references.   The upbeat [how-turkey-saved-jewish-lives](https://jewishinfonews.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/turkey-and-the-holocaust-how-turkey-saved-jewish-lives/) fills in detail that probably covers the instances I mentioned to above.  The [review](http://mepc.org/turkey-jews-and-holocaust) of a book *Turkey, the Jews and the Holocaust* by Corry Guttstadt points to an existing body of scholarship on the issue of Turkey and the Holocaust.  The matter is far more complex and contentious than indicated in the previous web site.

Comment: Turkey is a bit different since there aren't any Turkish refugees in this conflict. But a good data point!

Comment: Wikipedia says there were about 1000 German-speaking emigrants in Turkey: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exil_in_der_T%C3%BCrkei_1933%E2%80%931945 . Other well-known emigrants were Ernst Reuter (politician) and Bruno Taut (architect)

Comment: And there actually have been some Turkish refugees in recent years. According to https://m.bpb.de/gesellschaft/migration/flucht/zahlen-zu-asyl/265710/demografie , Turkey was among the five most common countries of origin among newly-arrived refugees in Germany in 2018, 2019, and (the first four months of) 2020. It was sixth place in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, around 37000 thousand Polish civilians passed through Iran as part of [Anders' army](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders%27_Army). Not sure if Iran in 1942 fits your definition of "sovereign country", but then at that time there were very few sovereign countries in the Middle East and Africa in the first place.